# Easy way to cluster entries in a numpy array with a condition

Tags: python, numpy

Background: I have a numpy array of float entries. This is basically a set of observations of something, suppose temperature measured during 24 hours. Imagine that one who records the temperature is not available for the entire day, instead he/she takes few (say 5) readings during an hour and again after few hours, takes reading (say 8 times). All the measurements he/she puts in a single np.array and has handed over to me!

Problem: I have no idea when the readings were taken. So I decide to cluster the observations in the following way: maybe, first recognize local peaks in the array and all entries that are close enough (chosen tolerance, say 1 deg) are grouped together, meaning, I want to split the array into a list of sub-arrays. Note, any entry should belong to exactly one group.

One possible approach: First, sort the array, then split it into sub-arrays with two conditions: (1) Difference between the first and last entries is not more than 1 deg, (2) Difference between the last entry of a sub-array and the first entry of the next sub-array is greater than 1 deg. How can I achieve this fast (numpy way)?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: This sounds too broad of a problem. And why do you want to sort the array first? That would mix up all your data points. Instead you seem to be looking for discontinuities in the original dataset (and even that is very ill-defined).

Comment: I completely agree to your point. But please imagine this way.. what if the temperatures only monotonically increase/decrease (maybe not strictly) during the day. So overall observation will show a fixed trend with small fluctuations in between whenever there are few quick readings taken. I guess sorting the entire array can then help in regrouping.. (note that temperature is just an example quantity and was probably misleading!) @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні

Comment: Is it definite that there are always two reading from 2 hours?  But you do not know where are the readings of the first hour and the readings of the second hour.

Comment: Another question: the readings of the 2 hours are mixed, right?

Comment: Readings are mixed but they are such that sorting will not change the overall flow of observations (they are monotonically inc or dec, but may not strictly), so only the order within a set of observations might change. What I now need is precisely in the last part: given a sorted array, how to split it into sub-arrays so that the two conditions are always met..